# Notation for Integral Closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

Let $R \hookrightarrow S$ be two rings. Is there any good notation for the integral closure of $R$ in $S$?

I myself don't know of any established ones but not to have decent notation for this construction that appears so often. I have seen $\tilde{R}$ being used (in Gregor Kemper's A Course in Commutative Algebra) but we don't really see how $R$ is related to $S$.

If there really isn't a decent notation, then I would propose that we establish one, e.g. $\mathrm{intCl}_S(R)$. Though that again is quite long and well... it is not so easy to establish a new notation in mathematics, I would assume.

Comment: I have seen $\overline{R}^S$, or just $\overline{R}$.